# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in a Public Static function call

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to use the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript call in a function defined as public static? Doing something like

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public static List<Records> GetXML(System.Web.UI.Page page)
{
....

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('test');", true);

....
}
```

will error out on "this" and "this.GetType()"

> Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or a static field initializer

in the web page (using the paramquery jquery grid) I have

```
  var dataModel = {
  location: "remote",
  method: "GET",
  beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  },
  getUrl: function () {
            return { url: "/UserMaintenance.aspx/GetXML()" };
  },
  getData: function (response) {
       var data = response.d;
       return { data: response.d };
  }
 };
```

... or is there another/better way to display a popup in a public static function?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the static method you are referring to is actually a script method directly called using AJAX from the client. In this case you absolutely don't need any `ScriptManager` inside it. This script should be executed in the success handler of your AJAX call:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public static List<Records> GetXML()
{
    List<Records> results = ... go fetch those results
    return results;
}
```

and then on the client execute whatever script you desire when this AJAX call successfully completes:

```
var dataModel = {
    location: "remote",
    method: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
    },
    getUrl: function () {
        return { url: "/UserMaintenance.aspx/GetXML" };
    },
    getData: function (response) {
        var data = response.d;
        // Put your scripts here, not on the server:
        alert("test");
        return { data: response.d };
    }
};
```

Please note that I have removed the `jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` call from your `beforeSend` method - it makes strictly no sense to be setting this request header if you will be making a `GET` request. You need to set the `Content-Type` header when you are making a `POST` or `PUT` request in order to indicate to the server what encoding did you use for the body of the request. A GET` request by definition doesn't have a body.

Another thing you might notice is that I have used `/UserMaintenance.aspx/GetXML` instead of `/UserMaintenance.aspx/GetXML()` for the server url.

So to sum up: you should not be mixing server side code with client side javascript. It's better to have a clear separation of concerns, so basically forget about `ScirptManager` in your ScriptMethod, perform any client side logic you need in the success callback of your AJAX call on the client.

Comment: That certainly removes the compile error on the server side. On the web page (.aspx), the javascript calls 'UserMaintenance.aspx/foo()'. What would that call look like, to not error out on me?

Comment: Are you saying that this static method is actually a `[ScriptMethod]` called directly using AJAX from the client?

Comment: on the server side it is defined     [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]

Comment: OK, so it is indeed a ScriptMethod, see my updated answer for more details. You should be using any ScriptManager in this static method. You should instead be executing the javascript that you need in the success callback of your AJAX call directly on the client.

Comment: I edited my question to show the javascript. When I added the 'System.Web.UI.Page page' to the server side, the javascript no longer works. I get an internal server error within paramquery javascript, probably because the url call is not set up properly.

Comment: Where did you add `System.Web.UI.Page page`? You shouldn't be doing this anymore, please see my edited answer more carefully. You don't need any `System.Web.UI.Page` or `ScriptManager` on the server side.

Comment: Also notice that the url that you should be calling must be `/UserMaintenance.aspx/GetXML` and not `/UserMaintenance.aspx/GetXML()` as you currently have in your client code.

Comment: Also please note that I have removed the `jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` call from your `beforeSend` method. It makes no sense to be specifying this header if you will be making a `GET` request.

Comment: being rather unfamiliar with Paramquery and weak on jquery, you are probably right. The ultimate problem is that (before trying to do the alert msg) the code works when debugging in VS but not under IIS. Nothing is either returned or not displaying for some unknown reason, and I'm trying to figure out why, using alerts (no errors are returned either).